# Launching a website to be accessed globally

Tags: web-hosting

I have a website that could be visited by countries in different continentals. I noticed that most hosting companies have data centers in the US only, which might affect the performance when people from India, for example, are visiting the site. AWS and google own data centers all around the world, so would this be a better choice to solve the above-mentioned doubt? Are they using some technology that makes the website located in all datacenters ?

More about the website :
It is a dynamic website which depends heavily on the database. It mostly involves text. Few ajax code is there. 
It is a Q & A website.

Comment: What kind of website are you thinking of? Without concrete details your question is too broad. Setting up a world-wide selling system (à la Amazon) is not the same as setting a small website with few visits for publishing mostly PDF or static HTML5 documents

Comment: It is a dynamic website which depends heavily on the database. It mostly involves text.

Comment: Don't comment your question. Please edit it. And even the above sentence is really too vague: what does the database contain, how often is it updated, how critical is its Earth-wide consistency? Does it has to show the same text world-wide to the millisecond? What happens when two users (in different countries) see a slightly different content at the same time?

Comment: You should use this website for coding questions. This question should belong in https://stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You would use some sort of load balancer.

Such as

[AWS Elastic Load Balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)

[Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/)

Answer (score 2):

Cloud providers such as AWS has something called edge locations. When you deploy a website code, AWS will deploy the same code to edge locations around the world. When a user visits your website and the request reaches to AWS, AWS will redirect the requests to the edge location that is geographically closer to the user. So that the request will be served to the user faster.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that most hosting companies have data centers in the US only, which might affect the performance when people from India, for example, are visiting the site.

If your web site has purely or mostly static content, it usually won't matter (read about [web caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache)), unless its traffic is large. As a typical example, I manage http://refpersys.org/ (physically hosted by [OVH](https://ovh.com/) in France) and it is well visible from India: the latency is less than a few hundred milliseconds.

If your web site is extremely dynamic, it could matter (e.g. if every keystroke in a web browser started from India required an [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) call to the US-located host).

Read much more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and perhaps [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite). Don't confuse the [World Wide Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web) with the [Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet) (which existed before the Web).

If performance really matters to you, you would set up some distributed and [load balanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)) web service, by hosting on each continent. You might for instance use some distributed database technologies for the data (read about [database replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)#DATABASE)), e.g. with [PostGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/high-availability.html) as your [back-end database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-end_database).

Of course, you can find web hosting in India.

And all that has some cost, mostly software development and deployment (network sysadmin skills are rare).

> It is a Q & A website.

Then it is not that critical (assuming a small to medium traffic), and you can afford (at first) a single hosting located in a single place. I assume no harm is done if a given answer becomes visible worldwide only after several minutes.

Once your website is popular enough, you would have resources (human labor and computing hosting) to redesign it. AFAIK, StackOverflow started with a single web hosting and later improved to its current state. Design your website with some [agile software development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) mindset: the *data* (that is past questions and answers typed by human users) is the most important asset, so make sure to design your [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) correctly, taking into account [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)), and ensure that your data is backed-up correctly and often enough. And web technologies are evolving too (in 2021 the Web won't be exactly the same as today in December 2019, see e.g. [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/393837/40065) question).

If you wanted a world-wide fault-proof Q & A website, you could get a PhD in designing it well enough. Global distributed database consistency is still a research topic (see e.g. [this](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01756780/document) research report).